# Cq5 building a number increment/decrement box

Tags: combobox, adobe, increment, aem, decrement

[image]

the above picture is what i need to build in CQ5, I　have been digging around in [adobe cq api](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.WCM),
all i have found is `Class CQ.Ext.form.NumberField`

but that number field only provide something like textfield for you to manually entering number(this is not what i need)

can anyone guide me how to create such number increment/decrement box in cq5 dialog? with some code example please, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `CQ.form.Spinner` with xtype `spinner`.
This is a trigger field for numeric, date or time values.

The spinner uses `CQ.form.Spinner.Strategy` which defines its behavior.

The dialog config snippet is shown here.

```
<numfield xtype="spinner" name="./numfield" editable="false">
    <strategy xtype="number" allowDecimals="false" maxValue="50" />
</numfield>
```

For further info, check this [Spinner API](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Spinner) and [NumberStrategy API](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Spinner.NumberStrategy)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Spinner Widget with the xtype="spinner". There you can define the strategy of the spinner, e.g. the increment value. I never used it myself though, so I can't provide you with a running code example.